# How to select from table with JOIN instead 3 queries

Tags: php, mysql, join

My table structures are :

table1 :

```
id      |    title    |    category    | body
--------+-------------+----------------+---------------
1       | blah blah   | 2              | blah blah blah
2       | blah blah   | 3              | blah blah blah
3       | blah blah   | 2              | blah blah blah
4       | blah blah   | 1              | blah blah blah
```

table2 :

```
id      |   cid    |   type    |     link
--------+----------+-----------+--------------------
1       | 1        | c1        | http://........
1       | 2        | c1        | http://........
1       | 3        | c1        | http://........
1       | 4        | c1        | http://........
1       | 2        | c2        | http://........
1       | 3        | c2        | http://........
1       | 1        | c2        | http://........
```

Now I use this code to select from this tables in 3 separate queries :

```
$query = mysql_select("SELECT * FROM table1");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $c1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT link FROM table2 WHERE cid=".$result['id']." AND type = 'c1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"));
   $c2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT link FROM table2 WHERE cid=".$result['category']." AND type = 'c2' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"));

  ....
}
```

Is it possible to write these queries in one query for mysql ?

Comment: Second query : `WHERE cid=".$result['id']`. Third query : `WHERE cid=".$result['category']`. Are you sure ?

Comment: Yes, this is my problem, I have 2 types records in one table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON b.cid = a.id AND type = 'c1'
LEFT JOIN table2 c ON b.cid = a.category AND type = 'c2'
ORDER BY a.title ASC, b.id DESC, c.id DESC
```

maybe expanded with an `ORDER BY`.

You could also try `INNER JOIN` instead, if you only want to get those rows of `table1`, which have the requested rows in `table2`.

Comment: You are not selecting the `link` from table2.

Comment: Thanks, I use `ORDER` because may be we have more than one record in table2 so I ordered by `id` to select latest record, how can I do this in this query?

Comment: @Theox I use `SELECT *` which selects just everything.

Comment: @MajAfy You have to decide how to sort table1 too, because you must sort first this, than that. So what is your preferred order of table 1?

Comment: @MajAfy Use something like `ORDER BY a.id, b.id DESC, c.id DESC`

Comment: @GhostGambler I want order table1 by title : `ORDER BY title ASC` but from table2 we should select just one record like: `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group.

Comment: @GhostGambler your query work for me but How can I use `ORDER`  ?

Comment: I updated my answer, but see that this is not the same as the two queries with `LIMIT 1`!